# How to avoid designing classes whose member functions depend on each other?

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns

Let's say I have a class called Adder:

```
class adder(object):
  def __init__(self, a, b):
     self.a=a
     self.b=b
     self.result = None

  def perform_addition(self):
     self.result = self.a + self.b
     return self.result
```

If I instantiate this class:

```
myAdder = adder(1,2)
```

Then the value of myAdder.result depends on calling perform_addition() first, otherwise it'll always remain None. It other words, there's a dependency on perform_addition() for the value of self.result. And if we extrapolate, a more complex class can have a chain of dependencies: ie, you have to call functions A, B, and C before D, because they in turn populate the necessary variables that the next function needs.

Is this bad class design? What is the remedy for it?
I think the above is a example of: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_coupling

Comment: The solution in this case is to not write a class, but a function.

Comment: should `add(1,2)` be `adder(1,2)`?

Comment: This kind of trivial example makes it hard to understand what your real question is. Maybe you want to make `result` a property, so that it calculates its value dynamically by calling `perform_addition`?

Comment: Your code is not an example of sequential coupling.

Comment: I don't see a problem in having class methods calling other class methods to build or calculate something. Instead I see a problem when you *leak* those internal class details (of having to call method x then method y) to the class user code.

Comment: @progmatico which part of that is leaking ?

Comment: I meant if a class knows that some of its methods have to be called before or after others, that is knowledge that belongs to the class itself and that is not a problem. For example  an `__init__` method that executes several steps in sequence by calling other methods of the same class. I see a problem when instead the code that uses the class has to respect some method calling order against that class.. That knowledge is better hidden in the class, because otherwise you can't guarantee it will be respected, and you'll have to write code in the class to defend against erroneous usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a good case to make `result` a property instead, so that the addition is only performed when the `result` attribute is accessed:

```
class adder(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    @property
    def result(self):
        return self.a + self.b

myAdder = adder(1,2)
print(myAdder.result)
```

This outputs: `3`

In case the `result` attribute is expected to be accessed multiple times and that the calculation involved is expensive, you can save the result in an instance variable to avoid re-calculations:

```
class adder(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self._result = None

    @property
    def result(self):
        if self._result is None:
            self._result = self.a + self.b
        return self._result
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it all depends on what you want to do and how you want to go about it. the code you have is not necessarily bad, if you want a static dependency on 'perform_addition()' for the value of 'self.result' . But if you want a dynamic dependency, then the code below will be a good and simple approach. this way when an object is created by instantiating the class with values 'a' and 'b', 'self.result' will be automatically computed. you could also use more advanced tools like properties, decorators, descriptors etc. like i said, it all depends on what you want.

```
Class adder(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a=a
        self.b=b
        self.result = self.perform_addition()

    def perform_addition(self):
        self.result = self.a + self.b
        return self.result
```